# Why no intellisense when LINQ statement has no where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, intellisense

Can anyone tell me why I **do not** get intellisense with this code:

```
var testDocuments = (from u in db.TestDocuments
                     orderby u.WhenCreated descending
                     select u).
```

but I **do** get intellisense with this code:

```
var testDocuments = (from u in db.TestDocuments
                     orderby u.WhenCreated descending
                     where 1==1
                     select u).
```

Comment: Are you using Resharper or Code Rush?

Comment: I see the same, nothing but VS Express.

Comment: I am using ReSharper (4.5, VS2008), too - this is not reproducible for me. I get intellisence in both cases ...

Comment: Well, the first is `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm using VS2008 *without* Resharper, perhaps Resharper corrects it?

Comment: I tried this in C# Express 2010 and did not repro.  Can you post a minimal repro case; a single, terse file of source code that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run into this kind of problem I switch my coding style a little:

```
var testDocuments = (from u in db.TestDocuments
                     orderby u.WhenCreated descending
                     select u).
```

Translates into

```
var testDocuments = db.TestDocuments.OrderBy(u => u.WhenCreated).
```

And assuming the Linq object is valid it will pull up the intellisense.

Comment: What you're saying is: why write a query expression just for `OrderBy`? Good point, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the similar situation, then I added the following line..

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: This is the NUMBER 1 solution, always to check when LINQ is involved.