# linq not identifying query terms

Tags: c#, .net, linq, razor, visual-studio-2012

I created a usercontrol which should be basically populating dropdownlists in my form when the page is loaded and adding after submit submitting the information via linq to the the database.

The problem I face however is that the intellisense is not identifying the query terms such as where and select in my usercontrol. Any pointers to what I might be missing?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Linq;
using UmbracoProd.admin.code.Test;
using UmbracoProd.code;

namespace UmbracoProd.usercontrols.forms
{
    public partial class testCancellation : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
       private testhousingEntities canceldb = new testhousingEntities();       

        /*load form*/
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                InitializeForm();
            }            

        }   
        /*updating the database with new row of info */
        private void CreateEntry()
        {
            var date = DateTime.Today;
            var version = (from v in canceldb.CancellationVersions
                            where v.Active
                            select v).FirstOrDefault();

            if (version == null)
            {
              throw new NullReferenceException();
            }            

            //Try to create an entry for the database.  Upon failure, sends the exception to ThrowDbError();
            try
            {
                CancellationRequest cancel = new CancellationRequest();

                //cancel.Semester=ddlSemester.DataTextField.ToString();
                cancel.SubmitDate = date;
                cancel.StudentID = txtStudentId.ToString();
                cancel.FirstName = txtFirstName.ToString();
                cancel.MiddleName = txtMiddleName.ToString();
                cancel.LastName = txtLastName.ToString();
                cancel.AptBuilding = txtAptBuilding.ToString();
                cancel.AptNumber = txtAptNumber.ToString();
                cancel.PermAddress = txtPermAddress.ToString();
                cancel.PermCity = txtPermCity.ToString();
                cancel.PermZip = txtPermZip.ToString();
                cancel.PermState = ddlState.SelectedItem.ToString();
                cancel.Phone = txtPhone.ToString();
                cancel.Email = txtEmail.ToString();
                cancel.Reason = rbCancellation.SelectedItem.ToString();
                cancel.Other = txtOther.ToString();

                canceldb.CancellationRequests.Add(cancel);
                canceldb.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception oe)
            {
                ThrowDbError(oe);
            }
        }

        /*database exception error*/
        private void ThrowDbError(Exception oe)
        {
            canceldb.Dispose();
            Session.Contents.Add("FormException", oe);
            Response.Redirect("/DBError/", true);
        }

        protected void FormSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
              CreateEntry();
            }
            catch (Exception oe)
            {
              ThrowDbError(oe);
            }
        }      
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code to your question?

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I edited the question to include the code. You could check it above. Thanks again for your help

Comment: So the intellisense problem is where in your code?

Comment: Ok. I've never really had intellisense for that kind of stuff...Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341763/why-no-intellisense-when-linq-statement-has-no-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to add `@using System.Linq` to the top of each view?

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I edited the question to include the code. You could check it above. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I think the important bit is actually the `InitializeForm()` method

Comment: Well see for some reason intellisense does not pick up the key words such as from, where and select so i was wondering what could be the problem

Comment: Please post the `InitializeForm()` method

Comment: private void InitializeForm()
  {
     var version = (from v in canceldb.CancellationVersions
                    where v.Active
                    select v).FirstOrDefault();                    
        }

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that actually needs LINQ methods applying to it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not that your missing a reference to System.Linq it may be that you have some kind object that is of a type that can return AsQueryable().  If it can return that and it will fix your issue.

Comment: I think you mean "a type that can return an `IEnumerable`."

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I edited the question to include the code. You could check it above. Thanks again for your help